# Optimize the function in React. Having setState key as a props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having this function, which basically defines which form input to listen to. However as input is growing, so the function is growing also.

I was thinking about passing an id and compare it with the value of the key of the state so this state will change.

```
onChange = event => {
  if (event.target.id === "Name") {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  } else if (event.target.id === "Position") {
    this.setState({
      position: event.target.value
    });
  } else if (event.target.id === "Text") {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  }
};
```

So how to do it properly with the state?

I was thinking something like this. So the input form call the function with the id value and it finds a state with the same name|value.

```
onChange = (event, id) => {
  this.setState({
  { id value as a key?}: event.target.value
  })
}
```

However, do not understand how to write it correctly. Any help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
onChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    })
}
```

also change your element id to `name`, `position` and `text`

Answer (score 1):

More likely that you should use [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

`useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one`